# Hive: what happens if I delete file that is being queried at the moment?

Tags: hadoop, hive, delete-file

Let's say we have a Hive table stored on HDFS as directory like this:

```
data/
 |-- file1
 |-- file2
 |-- file3
```

What happens if I **start long query** over this directory and then **delete one of the files**?

---

I can think of 3 scenarios:

1. File descriptors are opened at the beginning and data is kept until the end of the query, even though file paths aren't available for new queries anymore.
2. Hive remembers file paths and fails the query if it cannot find deleted files.
3. Hive doesn't remember file paths and takes only files that are in the directory right now.

---

If Hive behaves like (2) and it isn't safe to delete the files during the query, **what is the proper way to drop old data from the directory being queried**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @Shankarsh, Hive tries to coordinate its queries using a "lock" table in its metastore DB. Try running the `show locks ;` command while another session is running a long SELECT or INSERT query, and yet another session tries to ALTER the table (having to wait until it can acquire an exclusive lock) to see by yourself.

Unfortunately that will not prevent a direct HDFS access to the files and directories. AFAIK there is only one type of lock in HDFS, and it's an exclusive lock used to create/append/truncate the file (or the last block in an existing file).

Typical scenario: you submit a query; Hive retrieves the list of files and file blocks *at query compile time* then launches some mappers to read from these blocks; meanwhile another job requests deletion of one of the files ==> one of the mappers will **crash** with `FileNotFoundException` *(I've been there!)*

Another typical scenario: ...meanwhile another job creates a new file, or appends a new block to an existing file ==> that data will never be accessed -- and that's not a bad thing by the way.

Bottom line: avoid deleting files in a HDFS directory used by a Hive table (whether managed or external) *unless* you can make sure that no query is currently running, or may be running soon. If you want to delete *all* the files at once, for a managed table, use `TRUNCATE` at table/partition level and let Hive do the dirty coordination stuff.

In some cases you might try a complicated trick with a temp table having a single partition, an `EXCHANGE PARTITION` Hive command (...coordination...), then the HDFS deletion *in the temp directory*, then another `EXCHANGE PARTITION` to return all remaining files back in place -- but of course, any query started in between would see an empty table, and that could be a problem.

Comment: ...plus, any data INSERTed in betwen would be sent to limbo by the last EXCHANGE  (unless you INSERT it again from the temp table to the regular table just after that).

Comment: Everything needed for a great answer: response to concrete questions and description of how to overcome imposed issues. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I guess Hive will have do a table level lock(shared read only) and it wont allow any updates/deletes on the table, so ideally it wont allow data to be deleted.

Please have a look at this post as well:

[Hive Locks entire database when running select on one table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894955/hive-locks-entire-database-when-running-select-on-one-table)

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I'm not going to delete data from Hive, I consider **deleting the files directly** (e.g. using `hadoop fs -rm`). So Hive won't have a chance to lock it or even know about the change.